# C# DateTime is always 01/01/0001 when passed through method parameters

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to check if a DateTime is greater than another DateTime in a method, but when I try to pass it through the paramaters it says that one of the DateTime is 01/01/0001 even though I didn't pass it through as such.

Method:

```
int monthsCount2(DateTime date, DateTime birthday, int yOld)
            {
                int count = 0;
                if (birthday.Date >= date.Date)
                {
                    count++;
                    if (!(yOld == 0))
                        count += (yOld - 1);
                }
                else
                    count += yOld;
                return count;
            }
```

Using the method:

```
Console.WriteLine("You have lived through {0} christmases.", 
monthsCount2(christmas, birthDay, (int)yearsOld));
```

christmas variable:

```
DateTime christmas = new DateTime(25 / 12 / 2017);
```

birthDay variable:

```
try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Birthdate. (dd/MM/yyyy)");
                    string input = Console.ReadLine();
                    birthDay = DateTime.Parse(input);
                    if (birthDay > DateTime.Now)
                        throw new FormatException();
                }
```

yearsOld variable:

```
TimeSpan secondsTimeSpan = DateTime.Now - birthDay;
                double secondsOld = Math.Round(secondsTimeSpan.TotalSeconds);
                double minutesOld = Math.Round(secondsOld / 60);
                double hoursOld = Math.Round(minutesOld / 60);
                double daysOld = Math.Round(hoursOld / 24);
                double weeksOld = Math.Round(daysOld / 7);
                double monthsOld = Math.Round(weeksOld / 4.34524);
                double yearsOld = Math.Round(monthsOld / 12, 1);
```

Input - Console:
[Console - Imgur](https://imgur.com/a/5GlysAp)

Locals Debug:
[Locals - Imgur](https://imgur.com/a/7tXlHVy)

All Code:
[Code - Github](https://gist.github.com/mariothedog/562df7d5e9b0ce28d12135b898392a5a)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax to initialize a datetime instance is this:

```
var christmas = new DateTime(2017, 12, 25);
```

The constructor is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx).

And the reason why your approach did not work:

You are dividing 25 by 12, then dividing the result of that by 2017. as an integer, this will be zero, as a date this will be `DateTime.MinValue` which is 01/01/0001.

So why does the compiler not reject your attempted date literal? Because [there is a constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes an `Int64` that fits the division expression. It has altogether different semantics though, it represents the

> number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect syntax (or at very least not what you think it is)

```
DateTime christmas = new DateTime(25 / 12 / 2017);
```

The numeric values are integers and '/' is divide.

Instead you want to do something like this:

```
DateTime christmas = new DateTime(2017, 12, 25);
```

or

```
DateTime christmas = new DateTime.Parse("12/25/2017");
```

The format on that last one is culturally dependent.